# How do I configure Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I do not understand AWS Elastic Beanstalk services (documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-services))

1. What is a "service" in this context?
2. How do I create one?
3. Once created, how do I reference it in .config file? is it by name only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Service" is a general term for a long running background process. On Linux systems this is a daemon (usually managed by the init process), and on Windows systems this is called a Windows service.

Services usually conform to a well-known interface for starting, pausing, and stopping them. For example init managed daemons have a script that looks something like this:

http://werxltd.com/wp/2012/01/05/simple-init-d-script-template/

Creating Windows services is a little more complex: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983650(v=vs.71).aspx

As far as naming goes, the name of an init service is the name of the init script in `/etc/init.d`. A windows service has an explicit name that you configure when you build your service.